# Jquery DataTables Error

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-2, datatables

Hey there friendly stack overflow enthusiasts.  I keep getting this weird error when I use DataTables. Namely:
SCRIPT5007: Unable to get value of the property 'cloneNode': object is null or undefined 
jquery.dataTables.min.js, line 103 character 317

That isn't the only error that I get with Data Tables...

DataTables warning (table id = 'table1'): requested unknown parameter 0 from the data source for row 1

I get both of these errors despite forming a perfect table from which to get a reasonable Datatable. Code Follows...

```
<div id="populationInfo">
<table id="table1" class="scroll" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <td>
            Name
        </td>            
        <td>
            Population ID
        </td>
        <td>
            Description
        </td>
        <td>
            isActive
        </td>
        <td>
            Population Type
        </td>            
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>

   ...

    foreach(System.Xml.XmlNode node in nodeList)
    {
        string PopID = node.SelectSingleNode("./id").InnerText;
        string PopName = node.SelectSingleNode("./name").InnerText;
        string description = node.SelectSingleNode("./description").InnerText;
        string isActive = node.SelectSingleNode("./isActive").InnerText;
        string PopulationType = node.SelectSingleNode("./name").InnerText;
        //string PopName = node.SelectSingleNode("//name").InnerText;
        Response.Write("<tr>");
        Response.Write("<td>" + Html.ActionLink(PopName, "TemplateInfo", "PatientACO", new { PopulationID = PopID }, null) + "</td>");
        Response.Write("<td>" + PopID + "</td>");
        Response.Write("<td>" + description + "</td>");
        Response.Write("<td>"+isActive+"</td>");
        Response.Write("<td>" + PopulationType + "</td><tr>");            
    }
     %>
</tbody>
</table>
```

The Above code section is How I set up my view in ASP.net MVC2... Simple table setup, and based on a xml string that is passed in from a WCF service you create your table...
Below is my call to DataTables from my view.  I mean it works and I get a table back, but I fear that it won't work and when users use it, it will eventually blow up in there faces.

```
    <asp:Content ID="Content3" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent" runat="server">
    <link href="<%=Url.Content("~/Content/simpleDialog/jquery.simpledialog.0.1.css")%>" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />    
    <script src="<%=Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.dataTables.min.js")%>" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#table1').dataTable({
            "sScrollY": 200,
            "sScrollX": "100%"
        });
    });
```

Now I asked this question a couple of times with no luck... Don't want to beat a dead horse here, but maybe some one will know.  The good people at DataTables don't seem to know either. 
Why is that Warning occuring?  Is there anything that I can do about it?  Thanks.

Comment: Wild guess: did try using <th> instead of <td> on the <thead>?

Comment: hmm, I will be very upset with myself if that is the case, but happy at the same time.

Comment: Nah, that wasn't it.  What did you mean by that anyway?
<thead>
<th>
</th>
</thead>

Comment: No, I mean `<thead><tr><th>Header col 1</th><th>Header col 2</th></tr></thead>`.

Comment: Oh yeah, That is what I meant.
That didn't work.

Comment: You should be closing the `<tr>` in the last line of the foreach loop.

Answer (score 0):

This may be way late for the OP but the answer from veidelis solved the problem for me. If you have a `<tr>` where you meant `</tr>`, you'll get the error as described.